# Error starting app on heroku

Tags: ruby, git, ssl, heroku, sinatra

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby#deploy_to_herokucedar):
I've gone through all the steps. My app has a config.ru, a gemfile and a file that just says go! This was just to test the app running on heroku to see how it handled. Sadly I'm getting a very strange error.

Below is my git push as per the tutorial

```
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 596 bytes, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rack app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.1.rc.7
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       Using i18n (0.6.0)
       Using multi_json (1.1.0)
       Using activesupport (3.2.2)
       Using builder (3.0.0)
       Using activemodel (3.2.2)
       Using bson (1.6.0)
       Using mongo (1.6.0)
       Using plucky (0.4.4)
       Using mongo_mapper (0.11.0)
       Using rack (1.4.1)
       Using rack-protection (1.2.0)
       Using tilt (1.3.3)
       Using sinatra (1.3.2)
       Using bundler (1.1.rc.7)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby/Rack -> console, rake, web
-----> Compiled slug size is 3.7MB
-----> Launching... done, v5
       http://myapp.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:myapp.git
   d799d9c..93d7d15  master -> master
```

Seems simple enough. But the heroku ps gives

```
Process  State           Command                               
-------  --------------  ------------------------------------  
web.1    crashed for 4s  bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $P..
```

Naturally enough I checked the logs but they may as well be in arabic.

/

```
usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client.rb:409:in `read_logs'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/logs.rb:31:in `index'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:135:in `run'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/bin/heroku:30:in `<main>'
```

I did think that heroku was running apps on ruby 1.9.2 but thats not important. It would seem I'm missing some sort of ssl cert or variable. I definitely haven't used any SSL based functions in my 'go.rb' script but it still seems to require something.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

---

The config.ru

```
require './go'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Comment: This looks like it could actually be a problem with Heroku's tools, though I'm not sure. You might want to contanct [Heroku support](http://support.heroku.com/).

Comment: looks like there's something wrong with your config.ru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue really haunted me for a while. I still haven't got to the bottom of the problem but It has been fixed and hasn't resurface.

The sinatra application just would not start. After checking the logs, I found the word SSL popping up a lot

I wrote another smaller program just to test on Heroku and It had the same error.

I followed the tutorial [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) and It seemed to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion.  There was a bug in a recently released CLI version around SSL certs and it looks like you ran into it.  We fixed it and released a newer version which shouldn't have this issue.  So it shouldn't be something you run into moving forward.